# Vega Lite - change title of legend

Tags: vega-lite, vega

how do i change the title of the legend in vega lite?

See here:
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIeVyGmQ7CTq7AdzoxDiJnGWrlVpJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUAHkbOoAnmgAjEqR0XBoACwAvgqJyWSpGagATDlRMWgAbCVlmCnpaADMdXlZAAwtIEltFR2oBT0NqJ2Dw+1VYpP5qADss+WVTUtoABxFALolIMjqANZooJhpOMsgjlDBNLKycOoASkjKNAwQaGIDSjgsigbC+sjIFxA9DggUhADMaHBBMo0CBcg0lFcbqiAI4MJCyHSBHSkEBHEGCVLwxHI1FzUYZTHXW6yNgIJ5RMlFIpAA

trying to change the title to "poop", but its just not rendering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple donut chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "arc", "innerRadius": 50},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "legend":{"title":"My Title"}}
  }
}
```